Net MAUI Dependency injection does not work
I have tried to configure dependency injection in Net Maui app. I followed few online tutorials, read through several stackoverflow threads, however nothing seems to work. After considerable amount of tinkering with this stuff, I am clueless why this is not working.
MauiApp is rather straight forward.
I set here: Serilog, config, and classes from project library. This should work.
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            
            InitializeLogger();

            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            // Configuration
            using var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("BookLibrary.appsettings.json");
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
            builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);

            // Logging
            builder.Logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IBooksDao, BooksDao>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IChaptersDao, ChaptersDao>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IPagesDao, PagesDao>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IBookWriter, BookWriter>();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
        private static void InitializeLogger()
        {
            var flushInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            var file = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Logs/Log_.txt");
            
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(file, 
                    flushToDiskInterval: flushInterval, 
                    encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, 
                    retainedFileCountLimit: 22)
                .CreateLogger();
        }
    }

MainPage class, in the constructor I inject all things that I need.
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _log;
        private readonly IBookWriter _writer;

        public MainPage(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger log, IBookWriter writer)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _log = log;
            _writer = writer;
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

However in the App class there is an error connected to the MainPage() (it has red underscore) and info that there is no argument for required parameter configuration. If I remove the configuration parameter, then the problem switches to log and so one. It looks like the DI is not working at all. I have even installed nugets for: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuation.Binder, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuation.Json and Serilog.Extensions.Logging, but nothing seems to help.
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

    }

I have obviously done a mistake somewhere, but I am unable to find it on my own.

You're manually instantiating MainPage without passing the required arguments to the constructor of MainPage which takes three parameters. In order to take full advantage of DI, your App's constructor should take in the MainPage as parameter, as well. The DI container will then instantiate the required dependencies using the appropriate constructors.

Note that you're also creating captive dependencies by registering your MainPage as a singleton. While the MainPage's dependencies are registered as transients, they effectively become singletons as well, because MainPage keeps a reference to each throughout its entire lifetime, which is the app's lifetime. You may want to rethink this.

Ah, thanks. I did not know this, I will switch it to a transient.

I just noticed that you're using the MainPage directly without using the AppShell. AFAIK, automatic dependency resolution only works with Shell in MAUI.

Thanks for the info, I read through this documentation page.

You have registered the DI for the MainPage, so you don't have to use new MainPage(). It should be:
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App(MainPage mainpage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = mainpage;
        }

    }


I have done it already, but then I get debugger error pointing to App.g.i.cs: #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION             UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>             {                 if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();             }; #endif

Did you register the DI for the IConfiguration and ILoger?@julianuslemurrex

isn't it handled by this: builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);, builder.Logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);?

Sorry for my careless. Did you get the debugger error on the windows platform? You can try the android platform and you will get the detail exception message. @julianuslemurrex

Someone may need this in future, so here it is the complete answer, compiled from all the things above.
In the App class the MainPage has to be injected as well for this to work.
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App(MainPage page)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = page;
        }

    }

The MauiProgram Program class.
It is important that in the imports are both:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
Without Microsoft.Extensions.Logging this line of code will not work builder.Logging.AddDebug(); If anyone wonders this app is still using a serilog, however additional nuget Serilog.Extensions.Logging has to be installed for this to work.
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            // Configuration
            using var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("BookLibrary.appsettings.json");
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
            builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);

            // Logging
            var serilog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Logs/Log_.txt"),
                    encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: 22)
                .CreateLogger();

            builder.Logging.AddSerilog(serilog, true);

            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

Now everything could be injected into the Main Page and it works.
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _log;

        public MainPage(ILogger<MainPage> log, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _log = log;

            InitializeComponent();
            _log.LogDebug($"Application started.........{DateTime.Now}");

            var t = 0;
        }
    }

Additional notes. This is a MAUI project. So for the logger to actually log on Windows I had to add <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType> to <PropertyGroup> in MAUI project settings. Moreover I had to change the launchSettings.json in properties directory of the MAUI project line from "commandName": "MsixPackage", to "commandName": "Project",.
